# Trigger.io - FQL support?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, trigger.io

So with Trigger.io's [facebook.api function](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/facebook.html#facebook-api) this works fine:

```
forge.facebook.api('me', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Which is nearly identical to how you'd do it with FB.api.

But this example returns nothing:

```
forge.facebook.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid = me()'
},
function(data) {
   console.log(data)
})
```

Does Trigger.io support FQL?

Comment: If i had to guess, I'd say trigger.io is simply setting `forge.facebook` equal to the facebook js sdk. So it's probably literally the Facebook SDK you're actually using, just under a `forge.facebook` rather than `FB`

Comment: try calling forge.facebook.api('fql?q=SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid = me()', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
}) and see what happens

Comment: @TommyCrush Clever idea (it'd need url encoding anyway) but it returns nothing aswell, which is really odd. It has to be something to do with Trigger then. Thanks anyway maybe Amir or James could answer this

Comment: @TommyCrush     this works:

forge.facebook.api('/fql?q='+encodeURIComponent('FQL HERE'), function (data) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
 forge.facebook.api('/fql?q='+encodeURIComponent('FQL QUERY'), function (data) {
     console.log(data) 
 })
```